# [NextJS]Unable to load css file with svg image in node_modules using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, next.js

I was trying to add [React JSON editor package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsoneditor-react) to the project and it uses json editor package in node modules which was not getting transpiled correctly and was throwing errors.
The after some googling I added next transpiler plugin to get it transpiled correctly then it was not loading css and for that I added the necessary plugin and then finally when I thought everything worked in css it tries to load an svg and it is unable to load it and keeps asking for appropriate loader. Tried next-images plugin and also tried adding different file-loader,
css-loader, svg-loader and different plugins but nothing seems to work, do not know how to solve this as I am at my wits end .

And this weird thing happens when I tried to go directly to page where editor component is used the below error occurs when I load a different, page navigate to the current page. The component gets rendered without css it becomes just a collection of button and a drop down.

babel.config.js

```
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "import",
      {
        "libraryName": "antd",
        "style": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

next.config.js

```
const withLess = require("@zeit/next-less");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const lessToJS = require("less-vars-to-js");
const withImages = require("next-images");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

/**
 * Pass the external modules that needs to be transpiled
 */
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["jsoneditor"]);
// Where your antd-custom.less file lives
const themeVariables = lessToJS(
  fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets/antd-custom.less"), "utf8")
);

module.exports = withTM(
  withCSS(
    withImages(
      withLess({
        lessLoaderOptions: {
          javascriptEnabled: true,
          modifyVars: themeVariables, // make your antd custom effective
        },
        webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
          if (isServer) {
            const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style.*?/;
            const origExternals = [...config.externals];
            config.externals = [
              (context, request, callback) => {
                if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
                if (typeof origExternals[0] === "function") {
                  origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
                } else {
                  callback();
                }
              },
              ...(typeof origExternals[0] === "function" ? [] : origExternals),
            ];
            config.module.rules.unshift({
              test: antStyles,
              use: "null-loader",
            });
          } 
          config.module.rules.push({
              test: /\.svg$/,
              issuer: {
                test: /\.css$/,
              },
              use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
            });

          console.dir(config, { depth: null });

          return config;
        },
      })
    )
  )
);
```

Error

```
ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor-minimalist.js:29:104)
    at Object../node_modules/jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor-minimalist.js (/home/xxxx/xxxxx/spa/.next/server/pages/product/detail.js:208:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/xxxx/xxxx/spa/.next/server/pages/product/detail.js:29:31)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jsoneditor-react/es/index.js:7:95)
    at Module../node_modules/jsoneditor-react/es/index.js (/home/sachin/fr-mit/spa/.next/server/pages/product/detail.js:197:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/xxxxx/xxx-xxx/spa/.next/server/pages/product/detail.js:29:31)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./pages/product/detail.tsx:17:74)
    at Module../pages/product/detail.tsx (/home/xxxxx/xxxx/spa/.next/server/pages/product/detail.js:503:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/xxxx/xxxx/spa/.next/server/pages/product/detail.js:29:31)
    at /home/xxxx/xxxxx/spa/.next/server/pages/product/detail.js:104:18
```